# Windows remote desktop is blocked by my country and the internet is very restricted

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have a dedicated server but my country recently blocked remote desktop connection, when i try to connect, i enter the username and password, then remote desktop connection window stuck at "Securing remote session", are there any way to bypass this blocking? are there a way to connect to my remote desktop using some proxy, i use freegate, can it be useful?

**EDIT**:

The problem is not with my server, because i have an access to 4 dedicated servers, and recently i lost the connection with them all, my country has changed there internet policy and blocked many services such as FTP, and many websites such as facebook!

Comment: FYI for all posters the OP is in Syria, the current environment there may have a lot to do with this.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/394284/cant-connect-to-remote-desktop-gateway-server-because-of-in-self-signed-certifi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could setup Remote Desktop Gateway Server on one of your servers.  That will make remote desktop traffic go over HTTPS, which hopefully is still allowed.

Or you could connect through a VPN - what kind of VPN depends very much on what your country is blocking.

Or you could move to a different country :)

Comment: Great answer for a RDG... was just about to suggest this.  However from the post it seems like he may be out of luck, sounds like a DNS and Port blacklist was put into place.

Comment: If Tor still works there, RDP over HTTPS over Tor should work...slow as molasses, but should work.

Comment: I will do the last choice soon!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/394284/cant-connect-to-remote-desktop-gateway-server-because-of-in-self-signed-certifi

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have ssh port still open? If so, you can install a windows sshd server such as openssh server, and tunnel to any other port you want. You can just search for ssh tunnelling for your particular client and find many instructions online.

Another way is to change the listening port of remote desktop service to something that is still allowed.

Comment: another question: http://serverfault.com/questions/394284/cant-connect-to-remote-desktop-gateway-server-because-of-in-self-signed-certifi